# Upgrading SpringBoot 2.1.4.Relase to 2.5.0 giving NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, java-8

I am trying to upgrade our gradle spring boot application from 2.1.4.RELEASE to 2.5.0, it builds fine, but when I am trying to do a gradle bootrun, it is giving the following error below.

Can anybody help what dependency I need to upgrade along with Springboot version

Here is the build.gradle

```
project.ext.set("buildInfo.build.number", version)

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.5.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.build.ge.com/ARJLY"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
            name = "oa-publish-repo"
        }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        //docker
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'distribution'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

group = 'com.ge.digital.oa.moa'
archivesBaseName = 'moa-svc'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.1'
}

//dependencyManagement {
//  imports {
//      mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws:2.0.1.RELEASE'
//  }
//}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    add buildscript.repositories.getByName("oa-publish-repo")
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

mainClassName = "com.ge.digital.oa.moa.MoaApplication"

eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

sourceSets {
    generated
}

sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/generated']

configurations{
    querydslapt
}

dependencies {

    implementation('com.ge.digital.oa.common:oa-common:3.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        exclude group: 'io.micrometer', module: 'micrometer-core'
    }

    //implementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client')
    implementation('org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.1.9.RELEASE')

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3');
    implementation('commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4')

    implementation("com.h2database:h2")
    implementation('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5')

    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')

    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")

    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    implementation('com.opencsv:opencsv:4.4')

    compile ("org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.5")

    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:4.2.1")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.2.1")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa")

    annotationProcessor(
            "javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api",
            "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa"

    )
    
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.3.9.Final")
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vladmihalcea/hibernate-types-52
    implementation group: 'com.vladmihalcea', name: 'hibernate-types-52', version: '2.10.3'
    
    //OSS Scan fix
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.5.0'
    
    
    
   
}

//querydsl {
//  querydsl.excludedClasses = ""
//}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << "-s"
    options.compilerArgs << "$projectDir/src/main/generated"

    doFirst {
        // make sure that directory exists
        file(new File(projectDir, "/src/main/generated")).mkdirs()
    }
}

clean.doLast {
    // clean-up directory when necessary
    file(new File(projectDir, "/src/main/generated")).deleteDir()
}

sourceSets {
    generated {
        java {
            srcDir "$projectDir/src/main/generated"
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        //includeTags 'fast', 'smoke & feature-a'
        // excludeTags 'slow', 'ci'
        //includeEngines 'junit-jupiter'
        // excludeEngines 'junit-vintage'
    }

    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'moa-application'
}
```

---

And below is the Error I am getting when I try to run gradle bootrun

```
$ gradle bootrun

> Task :bootRun
2021-08-12 10:39:08.127  INFO 16268 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-08-12 10:39:08.608  INFO 16268 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$723d7fce] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-08-12 10:39:08.640  WARN 16268 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
2021-08-12 10:39:08.859  WARN 16268 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2021-08-12 10:39:08.874  INFO 16268 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-12 10:39:08.931 ERROR 16268 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:144) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:197) [spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104) [spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:70) [spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) [spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) [spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) [spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) [spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:373) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:331) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at com.ge.digital.oa.moa.MoaApplication.main(MoaApplication.java:16) ~[main/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
        at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.configurationPropertiesBeans(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.java:51) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$723d7fce.CGLIB$configurationPropertiesBeans$3(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$723d7fce$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$150902fe.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems it has been [removed](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1543) with the suggestion that `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean` be used instead, as of June 23, 2020.

Comment: I cannot find which class calls this Bean..is this called internally by some other jar

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you go into the depths of Spring to figure out where the error is occuring. Merely accept that it is and this is the workaround.

Comment: yeah.adding another version of spring-cloud-context resolved the issue..but now getting another error-  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/util/xml/XMLHelper

Comment: If this comment doesn't sort you, I'd ask a new question, but do you have [hibernate-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core) on your classpath?

Comment: Yeah..there was a hibernate-core mismatch in the classpath...now its sorted out